# Angular - Maven/Spring Boot CORS not working

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, maven

I'm am trying to set up an application that has an Angular front-end and a Maven/Spring Boot backend and have set up my first REST controller. My issue is that when I send a GET HTTP request to the backend from my Angular IDE it returns an error stating:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/getData' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I'm confused as I have set up the "doFilter" to accept all requests from any origin so it shouldn't be throwing this error. My code follows:

My APIController:

```
package com.SSCCoursework.controller;

import com.SSCCoursework.Model.SharePrice;
import com.SSCCoursework.Model.Shares;
import com.SSCCoursework.Model.SharesList;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin (origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
public class ApiController
{ 
    File Shares_File = new File("Shares_Data.xml");
    ArrayList<Shares> shareList = new ArrayList<Shares>();

    @RequestMapping(value="/api/getData", produces="application/JSON")
    public Object getData()
    {   
        Shares share1 = new Shares();
        SharePrice share1_2 = new SharePrice();
        share1.setCompanyName("test");
        share1.setCompanySymbol("test");
        share1.setNumOfShares(123);
        Date date = new Date();
        share1.setLastShareUpdate(date);
        share1_2.setCurrency("dollar");
        share1_2.setValue(12345f);
        share1.setSharePrice(share1_2);
        shareList.add(share1);

        SharesList sharelist = new SharesList();
        sharelist.setBookList(shareList);

        return share1;
    }
}
```

My SimpleCORSFilter:

```
package com.SSCCoursework.Security;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter 
{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, Connection, User-Agent, authorization, sw-useragent, sw-version");

        if (req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) 
        {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() 
    {

    }
}
```

My Angular code is just trying to use a GET method (this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getData') to print the data to the browser console but the error is preventing it from working. Am I missing a step in my backend?

Comment: Please post angular service code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily define a global cors config just by adding in your main application class where you start your spring boot app

```
  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                      .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST");
      }
    };
  }
```

for more details take a look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Comment: I've added the code you posted within the main application class above the main method edited with my rest controller details but the issue is still occurring. Could it be an issue with the request my frontend is making?

Comment: no take a look at that link you ll find more details

Comment: I've followed that guide and got the project working, so thank you for your help. I'm still unsure what originally caused the issue though I suspect it may have been how I set up the POM file in my Maven build.